# Attribute error trying to create a dataframe that includes nodes' degree

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I'd need to create a dataframe having two columns, one for nodes and the other one for their degree.
I calculated the degree of each node as :  `d = dict(G.degree)`
where G is `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(tf, 'N', 'T')`.

`tf` is

```
N   T 
name1 name 
name2 name1
name4 name2
```

...

The output from `d` is

```
{
'name1': 9,
 'name2': 1,
 'name3': 1,
 'name4': 1, ...}
```

I wrongly tried to convert it into a dataframe as follows

```
degree=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['N', 'Degree'])
```

but I have got the error ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 300 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want the following

```
data = {'name1': 9, 'name2': 1, 'name3': 1, 'name4': 1}

df = pd.DataFrame(data.items(), columns=['N', 'Degree'])
```

**Output**

```
>>> df 

       N  Degree
0  name1       9
1  name2       1
2  name3       1
3  name4       1
```

Comment: thank you HarryPlotter! Yes, this is what I wanted :)